# clear scope variable inside its $watch function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to clear `$scope variable` inside `$watch` function. but it is not working. How can I implement this one?

```
    $scope.$watch('selectedEmployee', function (value) {
     //do some stuffs
     -------
     -------
     -------   
     $scope.selectedEmployee ={};//clearing variable
}
```

This code is not working.

Comment: that will cause an infinite digest loop.  This feels like an XY Question; why would you ever *need* to watch a variable for a change and then immediately erase it?

Comment: once employee selected, I am doing some actions and clearing employee to get change to select new employee.

Comment: possibly you should add flag `true` to `$watch` from [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch): _When objectEquality == true, inequality of the watchExpression is determined according to the angular.equals function_

Comment: @MuhammedShihabuddeen, can you provied complex sample?

Comment: ok, but there are other ways than using `$watch`; plus, you still haven't really explained why `selectedEmployee` has to be empty.

Comment: Anyway, you should be able to avoid the infinite loop checking if selectedEmployee == {} before clearing it. Correct or not, this way you can still use what you are doing right now.

Comment: the watch expression (function) should **always** be idempotent.

Comment: `selectedEmployee` is text box model with auto suggested list. once user selected an employee. I am doing some actions and clearing that text box by making this model empty.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the general comments that watching a variable, and then changing the variable inside of its own watch handler is rarely a good idea.  However, there could be some obscure use cases where one would want to do this.

To avoid an infinite digest loop, you should ensure that the reference is preserved, and stable:

```
var empty = {};
$scope.$watch('selectedEmployee', function (value) {
     if (value != empty) {
         //do some stuffs
         -------
         -------
         -------   
        $scope.selectedEmployee = empty;//clearing variable
     }     
 }
```

This should work because the value will stablise to an empty reference when the digest loop runs.

However, this approach is still potentially problematic - you should have a "dot" in your scope model to ensure that it resolves to the right reference. Otherwise, when you overwrite the scope reference with an assignment, you could create a copy of the variable on the immediate scope that is a copy of the original scope variable.

Here is an improved example:

```
var empty = {};
$scope.my = { selectedEmployee = {} };
$scope.$watch('my.selectedEmployee', function (value) {
     if (value != empty) {
         //do some stuffs
         -------
         -------
         -------   
        $scope.my.selectedEmployee = empty;//clearing variable
     }     
 }
```